# Alternativa para __filename e __dirname em Node.js com ECMAScript Modules

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, módulo-ecmascript

A partir de versões mais recentes do Node.js, pode-se utilizar o padrão ECMAScript Modules (ao invés do *antigo* CommonJS) para a importação de módulos através da extensão `.mjs` ou campo `type` definido como `module` no `package.json`.

No entanto, entre as *diferenças*, percebi que não consigo mais utilizar as constantes (do Node.js com CommonJS) `__filename` e `__dirname` para ter acesso ao caminho absoluto do arquivo atual e do diretório atual, respectivamente.

A pergunta é: quais são os substitutos para `__filename` e `__dirname` no Node.js com ECMAScript Modules?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Node.js >= 20.11.0

A partir da *minor* [20.11.0](https://nodejs.org/en/blog/release/v20.11.0) (LTS) do Node.js, foram introduzidas as propriedades [`import.meta.filename`](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v20.x/api/esm.html#importmetafilename) e [`import.meta.dirname`](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v20.x/api/esm.html#importmetadirname), totalmente equivalentes a `__filename` e a `__dirname`, respectivamente.

Vale lembrar que, ao contrário de `import.meta.url`, que retorna uma string da URL com o protocolo `file:` correspondente ao arquivo, tanto `import.meta.filename` quanto `import.meta.dirname` retornam os *caminhos* como string.

Exemplos:

```
import.meta.filename;
//=> /Path/to/file.js

import.meta.dirname;
//=> /Path/to

import.meta.url;
//=> file:///Path/to/file.js
```

## Outras alternativas

### Equivalente a `__filename`

Existe [`import.meta.url`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v15.x/docs/api/esm.html#esm_import_meta_url), que retorna o URL (não confundir URL com caminho, ou *path* no inglês) do arquivo atual sob o protocolo  `file:`. Um exemplo:

```
import.meta.url;
//=> file:///Path/to/file.js
```

Mas note que isso não é, de fato, um caminho (*path*), mas sim uma string de URL (que utiliza o protocolo `file:`). Para convertê-lo a um caminho válido, pode-se utilizar [`fileURLToPath`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v15.x/docs/api/url.html#url_url_fileurltopath_url), disponível no módulo [`url`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v15.x/docs/api/url.html). Um exemplo:

```
import { fileURLToPath } from 'url';

fileURLToPath(import.meta.url);
//=> /Path/to/file.js
```

### Equivalente a `__dirname`

E, para obter o diretório do arquivo atual, pode-se utilizar a função [`dirname`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v15.x/docs/api/path.html#path_path_dirname_path), presente no módulo [`path`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v15.x/docs/api/path.html). Um exemplo:

```
import { dirname } from 'path';
import { fileURLToPath } from 'url';

dirname(fileURLToPath(import.meta.url));
//=> /Path/to
```

---

Vale lembrar que algumas APIs, como a [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/491857/69296) aponta, podem suportar instâncias de URL diretamente para a *conveniência* do programador. Nesses casos, pode ser realmente preferível utilizar essa abordagem, já que evita-se o uso da função `url::fileURLToPath` explicitamente.

É importante ressaltar, no entanto, que o `fileURLToPath` continuará sendo utilizado pelo Node.js, que [acabará utilizando essa mesma função internamente](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/bfa6e37204f1343c8a340f44c923858833da55b8/lib/internal/url.js#L1454) para converter a instância de URL passada em um caminho (*path*), tal como originalmente esperado.

### Referência

- [Documentação do Node.js](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v14.x/api/esm.html#esm_no_filename_or_dirname)
- [Esta resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50052194/7445826) no Stack Overflow em Inglês.

Comment: É são diversas a soluções com `import.meta.url` conforme a fonte [Alternative for __dirname in node when using the --experimental-modules flag](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50052194/1518921), quando vi a primeira vez essas respostas achei um pouco de exagero de quase todas, se sabemos que vai sempre retornar **`file://`** até um `slice` ou `substr`, ou qualquer coisa próxima evitaria importar um módulo todo só para resolver o `__filename` e `__dirname`. Claro que compreendo que são APIs nativas e por isso as pessoas usam.

Comment: Por isso mesmo formulei a resposta, para explicar e até colocar o que implica usar o fileURLToPath, já que a origem do problema começa por ai.

Comment: O que é dito na resposta já formulada, ele serve para resolver "mais coisas" e o problema de adicionar uma / quando vai tratar algo de Windows, pois ele entende o C: ou D: ou ect como outra coisa, nem cheguei a comentar isso porque já achei que era mais que suficiente dizer que fileURLToPath é feito para outros objetivos, usa-lo como nas respostas da fonte https://stackoverflow.com/a/50052194/1518921 pode até funcionar, não quer dizer que seja o objetivo ou o meio principal, Já que dá para resolver leitura de arquivos e pastas diretamente com o que tem nativo ;)

Answer (score 5):

Como a fonte no SOen sugere diversos usos para trabalhar com o `import.meta.url` [Alternative for __dirname in node when using the --experimental-modules flag](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50052194/1518921), no entanto o que não foi falado é que o propósito do `fileURLToPath` é além de "resolver" URLs com `file://`, como a própria documentação demonstra ([`url.fileURLToPath`](https://nodejs.org/api/url.html#url_url_fileurltopath_url)):

```
fileURLToPath('file:///C:/path/');    // Saída:   C:\path\ (Windows)
fileURLToPath('file://nas/foo.txt');  // Saída:   \\nas\foo.txt (Windows)
fileURLToPath('file:///你好.txt');    // Saída:   /你好.txt (POSIX)
fileURLToPath('file:///hello world'); // Saída:   /hello world (POSIX)
```

Ou seja, ele ajusta para o sistema operacional também, isso é útil aonde realmente é estrito a necessidade dos separadores para o sistema operacional especifico (Windows ou POSIX) e para tratar URLs que esteja codificadas com "porcentagem".

Se a necessidade de obter o caminho do script atual não é estrito ao "separador de pastas" e o `import.meta.url` não traz a URL codificada, então não precisa do `fileURLToPath`, podemos simplesmente podemos trabalhar com o objeto [`URL`](https://nodejs.org/api/url.html) (veja também https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL), inclusive a própria documentação do Node sugere que use assim:

- [**No __filename or __dirname**](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest/docs/api/esm.html#esm_no_filename_or_dirname)

Geralmente precisamos de `__dirname` para obter outro arquivo no mesmo nível do script ou módulo que está sendo executado, então bastaria usar isso:

```
console.log(new URL('./foo.txt', import.meta.url));
```

Pronto, o `new URL` já trata o caminho, sem precisar concatenar, sem precisar fazer nada muito além, claro que isso vai retornar uma objeto `URL`, mas as funções nativas estão prontas para isso, por exemplo, se desejar ler um arquivo (usei o `toString` só para ver output, o ideal é trabalhar com `stream`)

Observe que na maioria (se não todos) métodos comuns para trabalhar com "stream", tem o parâmetro que aceita [`<URL>`](https://nodejs.org/api/url.html), exemplos:

| Method | path param supports |
| --- | --- |
| [`fs.readFile(path[, options], callback)`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfile_path_options_callback) | `<string>`, `<Buffer>`, **`<URL>`**, `<integer>` |
| [`fs.readFileSync(path[, options])`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfilesync_path_options) | `<string>`, `<Buffer>`, **`<URL>`**, `<integer>` |
| [`fs.readdir(path[, options], callback)`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readdir_path_options_callback) | `<string>`, `<Buffer>`, **`<URL>`** |
| [`fs.readdirSync(path[, options])`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readdirsync_path_options) | `<string>`, `<Buffer>`, **`<URL>`**, `<integer>` |
| [`fsPromises.readdir(path[, options])`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fspromises_readdir_path_options) | `<string>`, `<Buffer>`, **`<URL>`** |
| [`fsPromises.readFile(path[, options])`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fspromises_readfile_path_options) | `<string>`, `<Buffer>`, **`<URL>`**, `<FileHandle>` |

**Exemplos:**

```
import { readFileSync } from 'fs';

const output = readFileSync(new URL('./foo.txt', import.meta.url));

console.log(output.toString());
```

Se deseja listar o conteúdo de uma pasta:

```
import { readdirSync } from 'fs';

readdirSync(new URL('./', import.meta.url)).forEach(function (dirContent) {
  console.log(dirContent);
});
```

Agora claro que concordo que se a intenção é fazer um "log próprio" ou coisas do tipo até vale algumas coisas feitas "na mão" com criar o seu próprio `__dirname`, mas para o uso normal do que o Node.js já oferece, dentro do ESMODULES é totalmente possível não depender nem de `__filename` e nem de `__dirname`, pois os recursos nativos com `new URL` já resolvem.

---

Observe que se você estiver interessado em usar algo como "require" em momentos estratégicos e precisa do caminho absoluto a partir do script principal, você pode usar `module.createRequire(filename)` (somente Node.js v12.2.0+) combinado com `import.meta.url` para carregar scripts em níveis diferentes do nível do script atual, pois isso já **ajuda evitar a necessidade do `__dirname`**, um exemplo usando o `import.meta.url` com `module.createRequire`:

```
import { createRequire } from 'module';
const require = createRequire(import.meta.url);

// foo-bar.js is a CommonJS module.
const fooBar = require('./foo-bar');

fooBar();
```

Conteúdo do `foo-bar.js`:

```
module.exports = () => {
    console.log('hello world!');
};
```

O que seria semelhante a fazer sem o "ECMAScript Modules":

```
const fooBar = require('./foo-bar');
```

Comment: @LuizFelipe a alternativa é "não precisa disso", a ideia é que se existe um caminho que funciona não tem o porque remendar ou fazer gambiarras para simular o __dirname e __filename, o new URL + import.meta.url já resolvem tudo nativamente **sem precisar de strings** ;)

Comment: @LuizFelipe o que perfeitamente new URL + import.meta.url com as APIs nativas resolvem ;), como descrito na resposta.